# Apply on two similar lists gives two different results

Tags: r, function, sapply

I created a function to calculate a value called "participation coefficient", and have tested the function with a short list, like so

```
testList<-c(568120,711503,1077594)
testResults<-(sapply(testList, function(x) participationCoefficient(x)))
```

Which gives me:

```
> testResults
               [,1]           [,2]            [,3]
[1,] 568120.0000000 711503.0000000 1077594.0000000
[2,]      0.7333333      0.8780488       0.4166667
```

Now, when I try to create a list from another source

```
>authList<-moduleCalcs[[x]]$authId
> authList[1:5]
[1] 548114 553928 553929 556071 559044
```

And use the apply function

```
> testResults<-(sapply(authList, function(y) participationCoefficient(y)))
```

I get

> ```
> Error in provideDimnames(x) : 
>   length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
> Called from: top level
> ```

So I tried to send a shortened authList but I still get the same errors. I am a bit confused as to what is going on here.

Also, here is the code for the function, in case it is necessary

```
participationCoefficient<-function(auth){
  outmod<-as.data.frame(table(subset(m2$moduleId.x,(m2$A2==auth | m2$A1==auth) & m2$moduleId.y!=m2$moduleId.x)))
  deg<-nrow(subset(m2,m2$A1==auth | m2$A2==auth))
  partcoef<-1-(Reduce("+",(outmod$Freq/deg)))
  answer<-c(auth,partcoef)
  rm(deg,outmod,partcoef)
  return(answer)
}
```

Any idea on why this would happen?

Edit

Here is some data that can be used for m2. I am not sure if this is the best way to share it. If not, please let me know if there is another way.

```
authList
[1] 548114 553928

 A2 A1  moduleId.x   moduleId.y
1013122 553928  1   1
1066822 548114  1   1
548114  722690  1   1
548114  666417  1   1
548114  854300  1   1
548114  842554  1   1
548114  991715  1   1
553928  710558  1   1
553928  767591  2   1
553928  718371  1   1
553928  649043  1   1
553928  601167  1   1
553928  637192  2   1
553928  710304  1   1
553928  559044  1   1
563965  553928  1   1
571821  553928  1   1
661623  553928  1   1
682197  553928  1   1
682886  553928  1   1
683583  553928  1   1
712141  553928  1   1
716224  553928  1   1
723022  553928  1   1
851338  553928  1   1
934132  553928  1   1
995296  553928  1   1
```

Comment: Your error is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your function uses the variable `m2` which is not defined. Please take the time to include a sample that we can copy/paste to recreate the error. This will make it much easier to help you. Simplify your code to the minimal amount to trigger the error.

Comment: See the examples in the link I provided on [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for better ways to include sample data. A `dput()` is much easier to work with than the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance what was happening was that the subset command here

```
outmod<-as.data.frame(table(subset(m2$moduleId.x,(m2$A2==auth | m2$A1==auth) & m2$moduleId.y!=m2$moduleId.x)))
```

was returning an empty set, which was causing problems for the table function. I had to add a conditional statement in the function to safeguard against this possibility.